# How to get Breadcrumb Trail from a book page?

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs, nodes, navigation

if given that we know the nid of a page in a book, how to construct some breadcrumbs or hierarchy from top of the book to the current page (nid)?

Comment: Do you want to get a trail or breadcrumb for the current page you are visiting, or for another page you are not currently visiting?